# Why does OSError - [Errno13] Permission denied occur when I try to create a virtual environment for python?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have python 2.7.11 installed on my OsX in a directory called python 2.7 in my Applications. I tried creating a virtualenv for this version using the following command:

```
virtualenv -p /Applications/Python\ 2.7 myvenv
```

The terminal returned this error:  OSError - [Errno13] Permission denied.
How do I fix this?

Comment: You are trying to execute the command in a folder where you have no write rigts.

Comment: Then how do I run the command that grants me that permission?

Comment: maybe you could run the command with sudo?

Comment: Tried that, did not work.